# Sharing Python Script Tool gives Error 000576

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, error-000576

I'm distributing a Python script tool with folks outside of my organization.

I had always assumed the .tbx file and the script were self contained.  But when someone else tried to run the tool, they got the error:

> Error 000576: Script associated with this tool does not exist.

Sure enough, if I go to properties of the script, it's pointing towards an absolute path on my network drive. I see there is an option under general to "store relative path names" but in the case of distributing this tool outside of my organization, this probably won't work either

Is my only option to send folks the .tbx file along with the raw python file, and have them add the script to the toolbox on their own?

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the script into the tool itself for easy distribution.  [See this link.](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/embedding-scripts-and-password-protecting-tools.htm)

Comment: hmm.  I only see a way to "add" a script, not import.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think so.  Add the script as normal, set the parameters as normal, when ready, right click the script and import it.

Comment: Even though (IMHO) the linked Esri info appears vague and counterintuitive, this is the correct answer.  I went back and found that the "Import Script" option was avaiable in my Script's context menu (not in the Toolbox's context menu).  After selecting "Import Script" the Source tab in the Script Properties indicated "<<Imported>>".  After doing this, I reviewed the context menu, and "Import Script" was greyed out.  I then saved the Toolbox (again) and imported the Toolbox on a different machine and confirmed that this solution was correct.  @DiamondJoe12 please mark this as the answer